# MacBook backlight keyboard does not work, and doesn't sleep when lid

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Pro 2012 13" (Non Retina) model,

The MacBook has no backlight keyboard and the MacBook does not sleep when you shut the lid.

I feel the issues are related and it could be damage to a ribbon cable, but I'm not sure what one.

I have tried SMC and PRAM Resets and it has had a fresh High Sierra install so it is not software related

Thank you for any help

Bradley